# How to print out values from fread() in C

Tags: c, printf, fread

I have a given simple code snippet that is supposed to generate a 128-bit encryption key. How do I print out the values to the console?
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 16 // 128 bits

void main()
{
    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*LEN);
    FILE* random = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
    fread(key, sizeof(unsigned char)*LEN, 1, random);
    fclose(random);
}
```

To be more specific: the instructions say: "Print out the numbers."

Comment: like `printf("%hhx",key[i])` in a loop ?.

Comment: also `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1.

Comment: ... and it is hardly worth malloc'ing a fixed sized small array:  `unsigned char key[LEN] ;` would be more appropriate.  In any event casting the return value of malloc is neither necessary or best practice in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating human readable binary data will usually involve hex or base64. Assuming hex code is acceptable:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<LEN ; i++ ) {
   printf("%02x", key[i]) ;
} ;
printf("\n") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most usual method of "human readable" presentation of binary data is to use hexadecimal, where each digit represents 4 bits.

```
for( int b = 0; b < len; b++ ) 
{
    printf( "%2.2X ", (int)key[b] ) ;
}
```